# ¿ como Insertar una caja de texto al final de todos los elementos con Javascript (SIN Jquery)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Buen dia**, he tratado de hacer una calculadora para hacer compras pero quiero agregar cajas de texto cada ves que necesite agregar un nuevo producto mi problema es que cuando uso "innerhtml" para agregar una caja de texto se borran todos los valores de las anteriores cajas de texto que  que ya existían, se que se puede hacer en JQuery con append pero tengo curiosidad de saber como se hace solo con Javascript este es el codigo que uso para agregar las nuevas cajas de texto : cajanompro[0].innerHTML +="";. En fin espero que puedan ayudarme les doy gracias de antemano a quienes me  puedan  ayudar

```js
/*ESTE ES EL CODIGO Q SE SUPONE DEBERIA  AGREGAR LAS CAJAS DE TEXTO */
function Agregaitems(){
  var cajanompro = document.getElementsByClassName('cajasnompro');
  var cajacantidad = document.getElementsByClassName('cajascantidad');
  var cajaprecio = document.getElementsByClassName('cajaprecio');
  var cajaresultado = document.getElementsByClassName('cajaresultado');

  cajanompro[0].innerHTML +="<input type='text' placeholder='Nombre del producto NUEVO' >";
  cajacantidad[0].innerHTML +="<input type='text' placeholder='Cantidad' >";
  cajaprecio[0].innerHTML +="<input type='text' placeholder='Precio' >";
  cajaresultado[0].innerHTML +="<input type='text' placeholder='resultado' >";
 }
  /*----------------------------------------------------*/
  /*ESTA FUNCION ES PARA MULTIPLICAR LA CANTIDA POR EL PRECIO UNITARIO */
  function Resultado(posi){
   var precio = document.getElementsByClassName('precio');
   var cantidad = document.getElementsByClassName('cant');
    var resultado = document.getElementsByClassName('resultado');
     cost =  precio[posi].value * cantidad[posi].value;
   resultado[posi].value=cost;
  }
```

```css
.titulos{
  text-align: center;
}
#FrmLista{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
label{
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 150%;

}
#resultado{
    font-size: 250%;
}
.Contecajas{
  width:100%;
 border: solid 1px red;
 display: flex;
}
.cajasnompro,.cajascantidad,.cajaprecio,.cajaresultado{
 max-width: 60%;
 float: left;
}
.cajasnompro{
 width: 60%;
 margin: 2px;
}
.cajascantidad,.cajaprecio,.cajaresultado{
 width: 13%;
 margin: 2px;
}

.cajasnompro input,.cajascantidad input,.cajaprecio input,.cajaresultado input{
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

.controles input{
  background-color: rgb(108, 108, 108);
  padding: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 49.3%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: rgb(255, 249, 254);
  font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
@media screen  and (max-width: 621px){
 .titulos{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<form id="FrmLista">
    <h2 class="titulos">Ingrese los productos que comprará</h2>
    <div  class="Contecajas">
     <div class="cajasnompro">
      <h3 class="titulos">Productos</h3>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del producto"  >
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del producto"  >
     </div>
     <div class="cajascantidad">
     <h3 class="titulos">cantidad</h3>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Cantidad" class="cant"  >
      <input type="number" placeholder="Cantidad" class="cant"  >
      </div>
      <div class="cajaprecio">
     <h3 class="titulos">Pre Und</h3>
      <input type="number" placeholder=" Precio del producto" class="precio" onkeyup="Resultado(0)" >
      <input type="number" placeholder=" Precio del producto" class="precio" onkeyup="Resultado(1)" >
    </div>
     <div class="cajaresultado">
     <h3 class="titulos">Resultado</h3>
      <input type="number" placeholder=" Resultado" class="resultado"  >
      <input type="number" placeholder=" Resultado" class="resultado"  >
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="controles">
 <input type="button" value="CALCULAR" onclick="calcular()">
 <input type="button" value="ABREGAR MAS PRODUCTOS" onclick="Agregaitems()">
 <label>Total :</label><label  id="resultado">0.00</label>
 </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qué tal? necesitas usar appendChild en lugar de innerHTML, te muestro tu código con alguna modificación, espero que te sirva:

```js
function getInput(type, placeholder){
  var nodo = document.createElement("input");
  nodo.type = type;
  nodo.placeholder = placeholder;
  return nodo;
}

function append(className, nodoToAppend){
  var nodo = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
  nodo.appendChild(nodoToAppend);
}

/*ESTE ES EL CODIGO Q SE SUPONE DEBERIA  AGREGAR LAS CAJAS DE TEXTO */
function Agregaitems(){

  var nodo1 = getInput("text", "Nombre del producto NUEVO");
    var nodo2 = getInput("text", "Cantidad");
    var nodo3 = getInput("text", "Precio");
    var nodo4 = getInput("text", "resultado");
    
    append("cajasnompro", nodo1);
    append("cajascantidad", nodo2);
    append("cajaprecio", nodo3);
    append("cajaresultado", nodo4);
 }
  /*----------------------------------------------------*/
  /*ESTA FUNCION ES PARA MULTIPLICAR LA CANTIDA POR EL PRECIO UNITARIO */
  function Resultado(posi){
   var precio = document.getElementsByClassName('precio');
   var cantidad = document.getElementsByClassName('cant');
    var resultado = document.getElementsByClassName('resultado');
     cost =  precio[posi].value * cantidad[posi].value;
   resultado[posi].value=cost;
  }
```

```css
.titulos{
  text-align: center;
}
#FrmLista{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
label{
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 150%;

}
#resultado{
    font-size: 250%;
}
.Contecajas{
  width:100%;
 border: solid 1px red;
 display: flex;
}
.cajasnompro,.cajascantidad,.cajaprecio,.cajaresultado{
 max-width: 60%;
 float: left;
}
.cajasnompro{
 width: 60%;
 margin: 2px;
}
.cajascantidad,.cajaprecio,.cajaresultado{
 width: 13%;
 margin: 2px;
}

.cajasnompro input,.cajascantidad input,.cajaprecio input,.cajaresultado input{
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

.controles input{
  background-color: rgb(108, 108, 108);
  padding: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 49.3%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: rgb(255, 249, 254);
  font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
@media screen  and (max-width: 621px){
 .titulos{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<form id="FrmLista">
    <h2 class="titulos">Ingrese los productos que comprará</h2>
    <div  class="Contecajas">
     <div class="cajasnompro">
      <h3 class="titulos">Productos</h3>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del producto"  >
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del producto"  >
     </div>
     <div class="cajascantidad">
     <h3 class="titulos">cantidad</h3>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Cantidad" class="cant"  >
      <input type="number" placeholder="Cantidad" class="cant"  >
      </div>
      <div class="cajaprecio">
     <h3 class="titulos">Pre Und</h3>
      <input type="number" placeholder=" Precio del producto" class="precio" onkeyup="Resultado(0)" >
      <input type="number" placeholder=" Precio del producto" class="precio" onkeyup="Resultado(1)" >
    </div>
     <div class="cajaresultado">
     <h3 class="titulos">Resultado</h3>
      <input type="number" placeholder=" Resultado" class="resultado"  >
      <input type="number" placeholder=" Resultado" class="resultado"  >
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="controles">
 <input type="button" value="CALCULAR" onclick="calcular()">
 <input type="button" value="ABREGAR MAS PRODUCTOS" onclick="Agregaitems()">
 <label>Total :</label><label  id="resultado">0.00</label>
 </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, si me funciona aun que  no entiendo muy bien el codigo que agregaste de cualquier forma lo estudiaré. te estoy agradecido

Comment: Me alegro que te sirva. Si necesitas alguna aclaración sobre algo concreto, no dudes en preguntar. Estamos para ayudarnos ;)